# 51 points lie inside a square of side 1. Prove that it's possible to draw a circle of radius $\frac17$ so that it covers at least 3 of the points.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, pigeonhole-principle

> 51 points lie inside a square of side 1. Prove that it's possible to draw a circle of radius $\frac{1}{7}$ so that it covers at least 3 of the points.

Here, I think that the pigeonhole principle may help, but I don't know what are the suitable holes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The square of side length $1$ can be divided into $25$ squares of side length $\frac{1}{5}$, and by the pigeonhole principle one of these squares must contain three points.

Next, $\frac{2}{7}>\frac{\sqrt{2}}{5}$ since $\frac{4}{49}>\frac{4}{50}$, and so the square containing the three points can be fit inside a circle of radius $\frac{1}{7}$.

Comment: hmm -- what you have shown is that a disc bounded by such a circle covers at least 3 points. Either the question is not formulated correctly or this answer is not correct...

Comment: @Thomas: I think it's clear from the context that the question means the disk bounded by the circle. It is quite common for people to be imprecise about this.

Comment: I think both of you friends are right: if we are to be precise,now it must be shown that the inscribed circle really covers those 3 points regardless of their position inside the small square

Comment: @Hamid Reza Ebrahimi: that won't be possible in general. Think of the case when all $51$ points are very close to each other. The circle defined by any three of them will have a very small radius.

Comment: If the points are all in a straight line no three will lie on the same circle.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: observe that a circle of radius $1/7$ contains an inscribed square with side
$$
L = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{7} > \frac{1}{5}.
$$
Hence you can cover the unit square with 25 of these squares, and so with 25 circles of radius $1/7$.